# Integer divisibility

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers, symmetric-polynomials

Given a (not strictly) decreasing sequence of natural positive numbers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ prove that

$$
\prod_{i<j} j-i \quad\big|\quad \prod_{i<j} a_i - a_j - i +j
$$

I already know a proof through the symmetrical Schur polynomial, but it's complex. I also tried to prove it by seeing the two terms as determinants of VanderMonde matrices, but it lead nowhere.

Comment: Decreasingness is a red herring, and so is positivity. Two references: ...

Comment: ... [1] Titu Andreescu, Gabriel Dospinescu, *Problems from the Book*, XYZ Press, 2008, §9, Example 5, and ...

Comment: ... [2] YHS, *A hyperfactorial divisibility*, version of 27 July 2015,
http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/hyperfactorialBRIEF.pdf , Corollary 11. (See http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/hyperfactorialLONG.pdf for more details in case you need them.)

Comment: (Notice that $a_i - a_j - i + j$ is best rewritten in the simpler form $b_i - b_j$, where $b_k = a_k - k$. It is in this form that the result appears in the references. Although, of course, your form comes out more naturally of the Young-tableau context.)

Comment: The Andreescu solution is really elegant! Thanks!